# Create own SwitchCompat Preference

Tags: android, android-appcompat, preference, switchcompat

Since the appcompat v7 is missing a `SwitchCompatPreference` it seems like it's necessary to create it by myself.

How can this be achieved? I googled a bit and found a tutorial for a `DialogPreference`. I tried to adopt it for a `SwitchCompatPreference` but in my xml layout it always says that this class is not allowed in the preference xml.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please use the edited answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do not need to create a new component.

First of all, you should use `CheckBoxPreference` instead of SwitchPreference, in order to support lower APIs.

Using the existing `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` widget, create a new layout file, for example `l_switch.xml`. Use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/checkbox" <!-- IMPORTANT -->
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false" <!-- IMPORTANT -->
    android:focusable="false" <!-- IMPORTANT -->
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Then, to your <s>SwitchPreference</s> **CheckBoxPreference** in `PreferenceFragment`,

```
yourSwitch = findPreference("key_for_this_component");
yourSwitch.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.l_switch);
```

or, to your CheckBoxPreference directly,

```
android:widgetLayout="@layout/l_switch"
```

This will force the CheckBoxPreference to use the `SwitchCompat` style.

Comment: I'm using this code, and while it does display the new SwitchCompat widget, the preference never actually persists. In your project, are you certain this is actually persisting the preference changes?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'll find a fix, and update this post.

Comment: This works but you lose the switch's toggle animation. I really hope they just create a SwitchCompatPreference in the near future.

Comment: You can create a `xml-v21` file and add SwitchPreference there, while the original would have CheckBoxPreference. That way, you don't lose animation on lollipop.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing.

Comment: I'm seeing an odd behavior with this technique.  If I have a CheckBoxPreference using the SwitchCompat style, and I change its state, its switch will re-animate to its current value (one time) the next time another setting is changed.  For example, if the switch is in the off position, and I switch it on, it animates to the on position as expected.  But then if I change any other preference's value, the switch will re-animate from the off position to the on position.  After that, changes to other preferences have no effect on the switch, until the switch's value is changed again.

Comment: Addendum to above comment: I'm only noticing this on Lollipop, and interestingly, the phenomenon only applies to the last CheckBoxPreference using the SwitchCompat style on the screen.

Comment: To make the switch animate, see my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536509/android-appcompat-v21-provides-switchcompat-does-not-provide-switchcompatperefre/31229920#31229920

Comment: @TiborP yes, animations would depend on additional code. I have provided just the basis.